# New \@startsection doubles text and adds too much space

Tags: sectioning, documentclass-writing

I'm making my own documentclass based on `article`. I need a new section type so I copied and adapted the following code from what I believe is the relevant code to add `\subsection` (at least in a simple document with no TOC and other stuff). Here it is:

```latex
%%
%% This is file `myclass.cls',
%% --------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[My Class]
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagefalse
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength\parskip{3mm plus 1mm minus 1mm}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\newcounter {clausula}
\renewcommand\theclausula {Cláusula \@arabic\c@clausula.ª --}
\newcommand\C{\@startsection{clausula}{2}{\z@}%
    {-0.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {0.2ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
```

However, not only do I get extra space after `Cláusula x.ª --` and before the section name itself but I also get a new paragraph with only the section name, so code like

```latex
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\C{blah}
Text
\end{document}
```

shows up as

```
                     Cláusula 1.ª --     another section
another section
Some text
```

I expected it to show up as:

```
                       Cláusula 1.ª -- another section
Some text
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: you make it very hard for anyone to help you if you post disjointed fragments, it is _much_ easier to help if you post a small self contained document that shows the problem, so people can run it and trace what tex is doing.

Comment: the definitions inside `\ps@myheadings` do nothing unless you use `\pagestyle{myheadings}` so that part of the question is clear, but without a test file it isn't really possible to comment on the white space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By itself it explains it, but it doesn't explain why it works for `\subsection` (and it's actually required for it to work)

Comment: You are right, either someone knows this, or its hard to figure it out (which I was hoping for, since this is from the article documentclass) OTOH I can only provide a full example by Monday afternoon.

Comment: the ps@headings code isn't used but `\subsectionmark` is initialised by latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I rewrote the question with a MWE (failed to make it shorter, all kinds of errors pop up), hope everything is clearer now. I removed the `\ps@headings` part as it was poluting the question (too specific and didn't solve anything). I know the `\let\clausulamark\@gobble` is part of the solution, so I'll let the answear reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

add to the end of your class the following

```
\let\clausulamark\@gobble
\let\l@clausula\l@subsection

\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\ifx\csname the#1\endcsname\theclausula\else\quad\fi}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this should be necessary? How can I expand this to add more sections? And what is the purpose of `\let\l@clausula\l@subsection`?

Comment: @Olivetree sorry in meetings al day don't have much time for an answer `\let\l@clausula\l@subsection` is probably wrong actually as you haven't defined subsections. You have not really said what you need, you could simply define `\@seccntformat` as `\csname the#1\endcsname` but the standard definition for display headings is `\csname the#1\endcsname\quad` which puts a quad space after the number before the title, the `\ifx` here makes it add a `\quad` space unless it is a clausula section, I was assuming you also had "normal" sections as well that needed the space, but perhaps not.

Comment: No need to apologize for helping me :)
I had not noticed the default `\quad`, maybe some packages (titlesec) change that on occasion. Now I can make an informed decision, thanks!